# Can I tame a dinosaur that is immune to being knocked out?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Certain dinosaur species, like the Titanoboa, are unable to be knocked unconscious. Is there a different way to tame these kind of dinosaurs?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Ark Gamepedia](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Titanoboa), the Titanoboa is **not currently tamable** by normal means.

However it can still be tamed with the use of the `forcetame` command.

Answer (score 0):

Lets run though your question

> Certain dinosaur species, like the Titanoboa, are unable to be knocked unconscious.

This is true so far and this is the reason you cannot tame them unless you use commands on a local or your own hosted server "`forcetame`"

> Is there a different way to tame these kind of dinosaurs?

At the current time of development the **only** way to tame a dino' is to knock it out (you probarly know) feed it berries or meat and keep it unconcious. The Titanoboa cannot be tamed at this point in time because you can not knock it out  **but** if you could knock it out I can tell you it would eat rotten meat and take about 600 Narcoberries and 300~ rotten meat to be tamed.

Comment: I should point out that not all dinosaurs need to be knocked out in order to tame, the Ichkyosaurous can be tamed but simply placing meat in the 0 slot of your hotbar and pressing 'E' when near

Comment: More specifically passive tames, Ichkyosaurous, Mesopithicus, and Gigantopithicus are not knock out feed it food tames.